# sql server analysis studio predicthistogram sort on adjustedprobability column

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-mining

I'm using SQL Server Analysis Studio 2008 to query a Naive Bayes classification model. I'm using PredictHistogram so it returns a nice table of support, probabilities, etc., however I want the returned data to be sorted by AdjustedProbability and not any other the other columns.

Does anyone know syntactically how to adjust my query below? I've tried several things but it's not happy in SQL Server Management Studio. Thanks,

mj

```
select predicthistogram([bayes].[code]) from [bayes] 
natural prediction join 
  (select 
    (select 'michael' as [name]) as [name_table]
  ) as t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
select topcount(predicthistogram([bayes].[code]), $adjustedprobability, 10) from [bayes] 
natural prediction join 
  (select 
    (select 'michael' as [name]) as [name_table]
  ) as t
```

TopCount is necessary to sort everything coming back from a predicthistogram call.